# Want to change marker present in example given below, having problems with figuring out calculations

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-icon.html

If you refer to the above example, you will get to know that the default marker is changed with the new image, for which following fields are entred/configured, I want to change marker image to something else, but not able to calculate/determine what values shall I put there

for example, if image is https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/map-marker-512.png
how shall I calculate these fields

Openlayers documentation says https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Icon-Icon.html

```
    anchor: [0.5, 46],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That icon is really big.

This seems reasonable to me:

```
anchor: [0.5, 0.9], // x center, y bottom: slightly up, point of icon not at bottom
anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
src: 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/map-marker-512.png',
scale: 0.1  // shrink by factor of 10
```

However, that image is fairly large, it would be more efficient to use one the correct size (and not need to scale it down).

[image]

[live example](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_6.14.1_modify-icon.html)

**code snippet:**

```js
const iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point([0, 0]),
  name: 'Null Island',
  population: 4000,
  rainfall: 500,
});

const iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  image: new ol.style.Icon({
    anchor: [0.5, 0.9],
    anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
    anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
    src: 'https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/small-n-flat/24/map-marker-512.png',
    scale: 0.1
  }),
});

iconFeature.setStyle(iconStyle);

const vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({ // VectorSource({
  features: [iconFeature],
});

const vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ // VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource,
});

const rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ // TileLayer({
  source: new ol.source.TileJSON({ // TileJSON({
    url: 'https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/aj.1x1-degrees.json?secure=1',
    crossOrigin: '',
  }),
});

const target = document.getElementById('map');
const map = new ol.Map({
  layers: [rasterLayer, vectorLayer],
  target: target,
  view: new ol.View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 3,
  }),
});

const modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
  hitDetection: vectorLayer,
  source: vectorSource,
});
modify.on(['modifystart', 'modifyend'], function(evt) {
  target.style.cursor = evt.type === 'modifystart' ? 'grabbing' : 'pointer';
});
const overlaySource = modify.getOverlay().getSource();
overlaySource.on(['addfeature', 'removefeature'], function(evt) {
  target.style.cursor = evt.type === 'addfeature' ? 'pointer' : '';
});

map.addInteraction(modify);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#map,
.map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Icon modification</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.14.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <!-- Pointer events polyfill for old browsers, see https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/elm-pep@1.0.6/dist/elm-pep.js"></script>
  <!-- The lines below are only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
  <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch,requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,TextDecoder"></script>
  <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v6.14.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/3.18.3/minified.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```